# Wordpress - Jquery not working when upload to production

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have a custom theme that include jquery. It's work fine on local, but when i upload the theme on production site, the Jquery seem doesn't work.

here is the preview of the jquery:

http://123.lyrics17.com/master.html

but, when I re-download link above (save "web page, complete"), the Jquery work fine without any changes of code.

you can check it in here:
http://123.lyrics17.com/downloaded.html

Is the Jquery not loaded? or is there mistake?

Comment: I guess you should check on the various 404 / 500 errors (some initiated by jQuery). The 500 error could be the reason why the jQuery doens't get included properly.

Comment: please check aria-controls in li in error file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser console is your friend. Always check for errors there first.

> Font from origin 'http://kppnjakarta2.web.id' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://123.lyrics17.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

As you may or may not know, there are certain things you cannot do, such as loading scripts, from other domains. I'm guessing that `http://kppnjakarta2.web.id` is your local machine and this is just a mistake in your code. Update so you are using relative paths would be my suggestion.

The reason it works locally is because the browser sees that the address is a local address and the same-origin security implements are turned off for local sites.

Comment: i'm forget to check the security section, so i miss the COSR error message. So, the solution is to move the source file to the same domain, isn't it? and the code it self have no problem, am i right?

Answer (score 0):

Please set attribute `"aria-controls"` li tag :

[image]

in  **http://123.lyrics17.com/downloaded.html**

```
<li aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-controls="tabes-1" tabindex="-1" role="tab" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#tabes-1">Semua</a></li>
```

in **http://123.lyrics17.com/master.html**

```
<li aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-controls="ui-id-2" tabindex="-1" role="tab" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a id="ui-id-1" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" class="ui-tabs-anchor" href="#tabes-1">Semua</a></li>
```

Comment: the attribute is added automatically from jquery-ui.js. the code is like this: <div id="tabes">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabes-1">aaa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabes-2">bbbb</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabes-3">Accccc</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabes-1">

Comment: only the id. heres is the code on the theme for that tab: http://pastebin.com/zX8buf3M

i think i'll check AndrewR answer, i'll try to move the source file

Comment: please check your php have you copied html section from another file?

Comment: i update the code. the tutorial is on here: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/  (I also copy it from there)

Comment: it is same but i have not added css so

Comment: maybe the problem is the COSR. I haven't try it. let me try that first.

Comment: the problem is lie in '<base href="http://kppnjakarta2.web.id/">', i just need to find a function that call it. or move the source file so the domain is same as the link stated in base. it's COSR problem like AndrewR answer.

Comment: I have no idea about it..it is bounce from my head..:D

Comment: it's ok, the important thing is the problem was found. thanks for your help.

Comment: glad to get your solution.!